# FLASK The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: flask

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/addarticle',methods = ['POST'])
def addarticle():
    return render_template('addarticle.html')
```

[image: Project folder]

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I'm getting this error how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do a 'GET' request, but the route says it only allow `'POST'`.

Change your route to

```py
@app.route('/addarticle',methods = ['GET','POST'])
```

You should remove `'POST'` if that is not being used.